# Excel VBA Paste Values to first blank row

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to set up an excel macro VBA that does the following:

Copies the value from B16 and paste it as value to the first blank row below B26. (So if B26, B27 are not blank, would paste the value to B28).

At the same time it also copies the value from A16 and pastes in the same row but in the A column, and same with C16 copying value and paste together with other values in column C.

So if B26, B27, and B28 are full.
The VBA would copy values from A16, B16, and C16 and paste them to the first available row of corresponding columns (in the example, it would be A29, B29 and C29.

Comment: Got any code you've tried solving this with?

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Values to First Empty Cell's Row

- Starting from cell `B26` (inclusive) towards the bottom, it will try to find an empty cell. If found, it will copy the values from the range `A16:C16` to the found cell's row of the same columns.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToFirstEmptyCell()
    
    Const sAddress As String = "A16:C16"
    Const dAddress As String = "B26"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range(sAddress)
    
    ' Reference the first empty cell below the given cell (inclusive).
    Dim dfCell As Range
    With ws.Range(dAddress) ' from the first cell...  ("B26:B1048576")
        With .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) ' ...  to the bottom-most cell
            Set dfCell = .Find("", .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
            If dfCell Is Nothing Then ' no cells are empty; highly unlikely
                MsgBox "No empty cells.", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Reference the destination range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireColumn.Rows(dfCell.Row)
    ' srg                                "A16:C16"
    ' srg.EntireColumn                   "A:C"
    ' srg.EntireColumn.Rows(dfCell.Row)  "AdfCell.Row:CdfCell.Row"
    
    ' Copy values by assignment.
    drg.Value = srg.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much!!!! I tried the first formula you sent and it works perfectly as values are not always in same row so I can edit that formula (see below). My question would be now, if I want the values to be copied to a different sheet, how would that formula change? Thanks so much! 

Comment: Here's the formula you sent first, the one I'm using and would like to copy values to a different sheet: